# Jcs cache version upgrade issue

Tags: java, caching, tcpserver, distributed-caching, jcs

I have upgrader my jcs cache from jcs 1.3 to jcs 3.2 version. I have configured jcs setup on 2 setup for testing. The jcs cache is replicating the values from node 1 -> node 2 vice versa its not replicating. I have put all the configuration files. But didn’t worked.

If im starting first node 1 and then node 2 then the cache is replicating from node 2 to node 1.
Vice versa its not replicating.

If im starting node 2 then node 1 then the cache is replicating from node 1 to node 2.